# How to make entire div clickable and fire an onclick event

Tags: html, css, polymer

I can only click the div border to fire onSelectChannel on on-tap. Check the following code. I need to know how can I make entire div to be clickable and fire onSelectChannel method.

```
<div class$ ="{{getChatListItemStyle(selectedChannelIndex)}}"  on-tap = "onSelectChannel" data-args$="{{item}}">
    <div class="chat_people">
        <div class="chat_img">
            <iron-image class="chat-image" sizing="contain" src="{{item.imageId}}"></iron-image>  
        </div>
        <div class="chat_ib">
            <h5>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{item.displayName}}<span class="chat_date">{{item.updatedTime}}</span></h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is a code?

Comment: Either `div { pointer-events: all }` or `div { background-color: transparent }` should sort out your hittestvisibility.

Comment: @Satif inclucded the code

Comment: on-click or onclick doesn't work?

Comment: @Satif on-tap is only working for div border , i need to make entire div to be clickable and with on-tap the onSelectChannel should be fired.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Polymer but I thought the entire `div` receives a click not just the borders - https://jsfiddle.net/x128dvus/

Comment: This is some problem in your code that we can't see. Propably some styles? like position relative and higher z-index? it can be anything. Provided code is not enough